# Spring Data JPA Bulk insert with time

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, timertask

I want to bulk insert my records to oracle table with spring data jpa. I created a list and items are added to list on runtime. List size 50 and if list reach to this size persis all list records to database and clear list also If list could not reach full size in 100ms persist to database all of them list's records. I simulated this way with following test class;

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@Slf4j
public class BulkInsertTest {

    static List<FraudRequestTransactionsEntity> requestTransactionsEntityList = new ArrayList<>(50);

    private Timer dbWriterTimer = new Timer("DBWriterTimer");

    @Mock
    FraudRequestTransactionsRepository fraudRequestTransactionsRepository;

    @Test
    public synchronized void saveRequestToDatabase(FraudActionsRestRequest fraudActionsRestRequest) {
        try {
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            FraudRequestTransactionsEntity fraudRequestTransactionsEntity = new FraudRequestTransactionsEntity();

            if (requestTransactionsEntityList.size() != 10) {
                if(requestTransactionsEntityList.size()==0) {
                    CustomRequestTimerTask customTimerTask = new CustomRequestTimerTask(requestTransactionsEntityList);
                    dbWriterTimer.schedule(customTimerTask, 1000L, 1000L);
                }
                requestTransactionsEntityList.add(fraudRequestTransactionsEntity);
            } else {
                dbWriterTimer.cancel();
                fraudRequestTransactionsRepository.saveAll(requestTransactionsEntityList);
                log.info("REQ DB writing time reached list size: {} delta: {}", requestTransactionsEntityList.size(), System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
                requestTransactionsEntityList.clear();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("[{}] Exception occured while FraudActionsRestRequest saving to db ", fraudActionsRestRequest.getTransactionId(), e);
        }
    }

    class CustomRequestTimerTask extends TimerTask {

        List<FraudRequestTransactionsEntity> fraudRequestTransactionsEntityList;

        CustomRequestTimerTask(List<FraudRequestTransactionsEntity> fraudRequestTransactionsEntityList) {
            this.fraudRequestTransactionsEntityList = fraudRequestTransactionsEntityList;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(fraudRequestTransactionsEntityList.size()>0) {
                long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                log.info("CustomRequestTimerTask executing with list size: {} ",fraudRequestTransactionsEntityList.size());
                fraudRequestTransactionsRepository.saveAll(fraudRequestTransactionsEntityList);
                fraudRequestTransactionsEntityList.clear();
                log.info("CustomRequestTimerTask REQ DB writing time reached timer time {}", System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Is this way optimum solution for my question? Is there any thread safety problem with multiple

Comment: why not u use spring-batch for bulk insert

Comment: I am using, created a list and jparepository's saveAll method already inserting them bulk according to following article https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-batch-inserts

Comment: then what kind of issue you are facing

Comment: I dont know how can persist records without full list just with time